# How to get back iPhone messages overwritten by restore?

Tags: iphone

I was planning to put some songs on my mom's iPhone, then when I opened iTunes and accidentally clicked the restore backup. All the files (photos, msgs, contacts, notes, etc...) of my friends, were transfered.

The iPhone was new and it wasn't backed up yet. All mtg mom's  important messages are gone. Can I still retrieve everything and how?

Comment: Is your mom's iPhone setup with iCloud?  If so, you might be able to log into the iCloud website and access the messages.

Comment: no, the phone is new and didn't have any backup yet

Comment: If there was no backup and she wasn't using iCloud, the only other thing I can think of would be to contact her cell carrier.  If she used iMessage then those messages are most-likely gone,  If she used regular SMS, which go thru the cell carrier, it's possible she can request a copy from them.

Comment: fbara is correct. Unless the phone was backed up elsewhere or logged into an iCloud account and had backup feature turned on (it usually automatically is) then the data has been removed and is virtually un-recoverable.